# R: Plot line chart using ggplot with missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a line chart with two lines in one plot using ggplot. However, one line chart has missing values in-between:

```
year<-c(1990,1991,1992,1993)
v1<-c(1,NA,NA,2)
v2<-c(2,3,1,2)
```

I want the second line (v2) to connect its first value in 1990 with its last one in 1993. Is this possible using ggplot?

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach reshaping your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
year<-c(1990,1991,1992,1993)
v1<-c(1,NA,NA,2)
v2<-c(2,3,1,2)
df <- data.frame(year,v1,v2)
#Plot
df %>% pivot_longer(-year) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(year),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+xlab('year')+
  labs(color='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I would like to expand the line chart to even three lines (i.e. one year column and three value columns). Is your solution applicable to that?

Comment: Yes, it should work regardless of the number of columns as long as there are no other columns besides `year` and your value columns. Otherwise, you have to edit the `pivot_longer()` call.

Comment: @nohomejerome I f you have more years or more variables it will work as data was reshaped. Let me know if you have other question!